# Linear regression factor

Tags: algorithm, math, lua, linear-regression

Given a list of points, I need to achieve a simple linear regression on them. This part is quite easy and code examples can be found in a lot of places.

My problem is determining the regression factor (measuring how much the points fit on the line). How could I determine such a factor programmatically, using Lua?

Comment: are you sure it has anything to do with lua? it should be very general, and lua has no built-in way to count it. you've got to get the algorithm and code it yourself

Comment: Are you asking for the algorithm for performing [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)? Or are you asking for already tested, working code for doing so in Lua? Wikipedia and Google have you covered on the first. And if you have the algorithm, then try to implement it in Lua. If you have a problem, come back and ask a question about it.

Comment: @LeleDump: Right, a general algorithm will do, too.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Most algorithms I've found only calculate the parameter for the line, but do not provide the regression factor, i.e. the adequation between the points and the line, which is what I need.

Comment: what do you mean by the regression factor? The F-statistics comparing the explained and unexplained variation? The p-value of the F statistics?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for the error ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
e$ lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> function calculate_MSE (points, slope, offset)
>>     local SE = 0
>>     local num_pts = 0
>>     for x,y in pairs(points) do
>>         local p = slope * x + offset
>>         local err = y - p
>>         SE = SE + err * err
>>         num_pts = num_pts + 1
>>     end
>>     return SE / num_pts
>> end
> return calculate_MSE({1, 2, 3}, 1, 0)                                                                                                             0> return calculate_MSE({1, 2, 3}, 1, 1)1> return calculate_MSE({1, 2, 3}, 2, 1)9.6666666666667>
0
> return calculate_MSE({1, 2, 3}, 1, 1)
1
> return calculate_MSE({1, 2, 3}, 2, 1)
9.6666666666667
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what you mean by : regression factor, but as said on this wikipedia article : [MSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error)

> Both linear regression techniques such as analysis of variance
>   estimate the MSE as part of the analysis and use the estimated MSE to
>   determine the statistical significance of the factors or predictors
>   under study. The goal of experimental design is to construct
>   experiments in such a way that when the observations are analyzed, the
>   MSE is close to zero relative to the magnitude of at least one of the
>   estimated treatment effects.

it looks like the factor you're looking for.

You can get the details on the calculations of MSE in the wikipedia article.

Hope I understood your issue and it helps

Comment: That seems to be what I'm looking for indeed. It would help to find an existing algorithm to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient is what you want.